# Opening a web app page using View Definition

Tags: azure, azure-managed-app

In my managed application deployment I deploy an App Service Web app.

Is it possible to use viewDefinition.json to create an Overview Command Action that will open the deployed site in a new tab or link me to that deployed site?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, frustratingly, it is not. viewDefinition.json artifacts do not allow you to read in any  sort of dynamic variable from the deployment, which would be necessary for something like this.